# How can I get the numbers from the following website (using nokogiri)

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

My code was working but now I am able to get any info from the site apart from the numbers that i need.

The code would be

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'curb'
require 'json'
require 'pp'
require 'openssl'

ejnumber4 = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.sazka.cz/loterie/eurojackpot/sazky-a-vysledky'))
ejnumber4.css('.number-row').css('.numbers').text
```

What I am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit more so we can understand it better? What numbers are you trying to get specifically?

Comment: @AndréYuhai , i tried to get the lottery numbers i.e. "1. OSUDÍ" but everytime i get " "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website gets the data from 2 consecutives API calls. The first one is to get the past draws list with the date and draw ID:

```
GET https://www.sazka.cz/api/draw-info/past-draws/eurojackpot
```

The second one is to get the draw result for a specific draw ID:

```
GET https://www.sazka.cz/api/draw-info/draws/universal/eurojackpot/[DRAW_ID]
```

You can try the following [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to get the last draw result:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

id=$(curl -s "https://www.sazka.cz/api/draw-info/past-draws/eurojackpot" | jq -r '.[0].id')

curl -s "https://www.sazka.cz/api/draw-info/draws/universal/eurojackpot/$id" | jq '.'
```

Using [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) with net/http:

```rb
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

res = Net::HTTP.get(URI("https://www.sazka.cz/api/draw-info/past-draws/eurojackpot"))
id = JSON.parse(res)[0]["id"]

res = Net::HTTP.get(URI("https://www.sazka.cz/api/draw-info/draws/universal/eurojackpot/#{id}"))
p JSON.parse(res)
```

Using [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) with open-uri:

```rb
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

res = open("https://www.sazka.cz/api/draw-info/past-draws/eurojackpot").read
id = JSON.parse(res)[0]["id"]

res = open("https://www.sazka.cz/api/draw-info/draws/universal/eurojackpot/#{id}").read
p JSON.parse(res)
```

Output example:

```
{ "drawId"=>2021255, "drawDate"=>"2021-06-25T19:00:00", "week"=>25, "year"=>2021, "draws"=>[[30, 4, 22, 47, 17], [1, 8]], "drawsExtra"=>nil, "addonDraw"=>[4, 0, 6, 9, 4, 3] .....
......
```

Comment: Hi @Bertrand Martel, Thank you very much. It helps a lot. I can filter out the details that i want.